# Filtration generated by the absolute value of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathbb{F},P)$, there is a Brownian motion $B$ on it. Fix $t>0$, my question is why $\sigma(|B_s|,0\leq s\leq t)$ $\subsetneqq$ $\sigma(B_s,0\leq s\leq t)$. $\subset$ is obvious, I don't know how to prove the $\neq$ rigorously.

Answer (score 1):

Use reflection symmetry.  For any ${\cal S}\in \sigma(|B_s|,0\leq s\leq t)$ and any sample path $u\mapsto B_u$ in $\cal S$, $u\mapsto -B_u$ will also be in $\cal S$.  So, taking $t=1$ for an example, it's not possible for a set like $\{B_u\mid 0\le B_1\le 1\}$ to be in  $\sigma(|B_s|,0\leq s\leq 1)$ since any attempt to construct it would also end up including paths where $-1\le B_1\le 0$.

**Addendum**: I will give more detail and use more precise notation.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that the two $\sigma$-algebras are the same.
Fix $t$, and let $\cal B$ be the $\sigma$-algebra being used to determine measurability on $\mathbb{R}$.
Then $\sigma(|B_s|,0\leq s\leq t)$ is generated by the sets $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid |B_s(\omega)|\in X\}$,
for $0\le s\le t$ and $X\in{\cal B}$.
If $\cal A$ is the algebra generated by these sets,
then, by our assumption that the $\sigma$-algebras are the same,
and assuming that $(0,1]\in{\cal B}$,
there is some $A\in{\cal A}$ with $P(A\ \Delta \ \{ \omega\in\Omega\mid 0<B_t(\omega)\le 1\})<\frac14$.
Therefore, there must exist positive integers $k$ and $l$, real numbers $0\le s_1<\cdots<s_k\le t$,
measurable functions $f_1$, $\dots$, $f_k$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\{1,\ldots,l\}$, and a subset $G$
of $\{1,\ldots,l\}^k$ such that
$$P(\hbox{$(f_1(|B_{s_1}|),\ldots,f_k(|B_{s_k}|))\in G$ iff $0<B_t\le 1$})>\frac34. \qquad (*)$$
Now, observe that $B_t$ and $-B_t$ both start at zero and both have independent Gaussian increments
with the same variances.  Therefore, they have the same distributions on any finite set of times, so
we can negate $B_t$ in (*) and it will still be true:
$$P(\hbox{$(f_1(|B_{s_1}|),\ldots,f_k(|B_{s_k}|))\in G$ iff $-1\le B_t<0$})>\frac34.\qquad(**)$$
Combining (*) and (**), we get
$$P(\hbox{$0<B_t\le 1$ iff $-1\le B_t<0$})>\frac12.$$
But, since this event is impossible, it has probability zero.  Because $0$ is not greater than $\frac12$,
we have a contradiction.

Comment: I don’t see why the last sentence is problematic, could you expand a bit?

Comment: I think it is a good attempt of the question, but I still cannot get a rigorous proof.

Comment: how can we get the equation star?

Comment: (*) is just a restatement of "$\exists A\in{\cal A}$ with $P(A\ \Delta \ \{ \omega\in\Omega\mid 0<B_t(\omega)\le 1\})<\frac14$."  The $s_i$s are the times used in the generating sets which $A$ is constructed from, and the $f_i$s and $G$ code the exact sets used and the algebra operations used to turn them into $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the coordinate process on $C([0,\infty),R)$. By monotone class theorem,
every set $A$ in $\sigma(|B_s|,0\leq s\leq t)$ must have this property that, ``if $\omega\in A$, then for any $\omega^\prime$ with the property $\omega^\prime(s)=\omega(s)$, $s\in [0,t]$ or $\omega^\prime(s)=-\omega(s)$, $s\in [0,t]$, we have $\omega^\prime\in  A$''. So, it is clearly that the set $\{\omega(1)\in (0,1)\}\in \sigma(B_s,0\leq s\leq t)\setminus\sigma(|B_s|,0\leq s\leq t)$